# How to penalize a predictor variable to decrease its feature importance

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have one predictor which is dominating my models, I still want to include it, but I want to down-weight its importance in the final model. Is there a good (sci)pythonic way to do this? I'm thinking maybe defining a custom `PenaltyTransformer` which introduces random noise into the variable, something like this:

```
class PenaltyTransformer(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns, scale=0.1):
        self.scale = scale
        self.columns = columns

    def transform(self, X):
        X[:,self.columns] += np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=self.scale, size=X[:,self.columns].shape)
        return X
```

... does this make sense?

Comment: Have you considered that you may just be overfitting your model? You could take [steps towards avoiding that](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-avoid-overfitting).

Comment: @AlexG thanks for the suggestion, it's not overfitting though, the variable is truly predictive, I just don't want it to dominate the model since this will not be suitable for my application

Comment: If you are using regularization, you can put a higher penalty on this predictor specifically.

Comment: @IgorRaush I am training a `LogisticRegression`, how can I apply regularisation to one variable only? (I can only see the `C` parameter which is a single value)

Comment: @maxymoo, this unfortunately isn't possible through `sklearn`'s implementation. I was commenting from a conceptual standpoint. Depending on the scale of your problem, you may be able to write a fairly short custom implementation using `scipy.optimize` and minimize a cost function in which you specify per-parameter regularization.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your application, it's hard to give a definitive answer on what you should do. A few options I can see:

1. Your noising approach in the question might be fine
2. You might use a model with higher bias and lower variance like a regularized linear model (I'm assuming you're doing GBM, RF, or something similar from the use of the term "importance")
3. You might exclude the highly predictive feature entirely
4. You might build a model that excludes the highly predictive feature entirely and then combines the resulting score with that feature in some way
5. You might also just want to accept that the strong feature is going to be the dominant factor in your model

Comment: Thanks for the answer Randy, do you know how to use regularisation on a single variable with a LogisticRegression?